# For which values of a and b does S have a unique solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let's say I have a linear system of the from:

A=

```
 ax + by = 1
 bx + ay = 1
```

where x and y are the variables and a and b are real coefficients.

If I want to get this system to Row Reduced Echelon Form to find whether it has a uniques solution (using Gaussian elimination). I should be dividing or multiplying a row of the system by "a" or "b" at some point. However, we do not know whether a,b != 0.

So, can I actually multiply and divide by a and b even if I don't know whether they are 0 or not?

\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&a\end{bmatrix} -> R1(1/a) \begin{bmatrix}1&b/a\\b&a\end{bmatrix} -> R2 -> R2 - bR1
\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&(a-b^2)/a\end{bmatrix}

Is it okay to do such operations? 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Recall that a $n\times n$ linear system has an unique solution if and only if $\det (A)\neq 0$.